# Set focus to first item in v-for using vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a `vue` app and I'm trying to set the `focus` to the first item in my `v-for` `list` but struggling

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-light" type="submit" style="border: 1px solid lightgray" @click.prevent="findTest">
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    </button>
</div>
<div v-if="this.Tests.length >= 2" class="list-group accList">
    <a v-for="(test, i) in tests" :key="i" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" :ref="i" :class="{ 'active': i === 0 }" @click.prevent="selectTest(test)">
        {{ test.test1 }} ({{ test.test2 | capitalize }})
    </a>
</div>
```

*Note the word 'test' has replaced my actual values*

I have tried using the following in my `method` which is called on `button` click but I keep getting get an error

```
methods: {
    findTest() {
        axios.get(END_POINT).then((response) => {
            ...SOMEOTHER CODE

            //this.$refs.0.$el.focus()
            //this.$refs.0.focus();
            //this.$refs.a.$el.children[0].focus();
        }
    }
}
```

**Error**

[image]

I am relativly new to `vue` but I have been able to set my focus using:

```
this.$refs.[INPUT_NAME].$el.focus()
```

But it doesn't like me using a number

```
this.$refs.0.$el.focus() //0 being the index number
```

As `WebStorm` complains saying:

> Expecting newline or semicolon

console.log(this.$refs)
[image]

Comment: where is the error `data`?

Comment: Did you mean to put `this.$refs[0].$el.focus()` or is there a property key that's just `0`?

Comment: where do you use `this.$refs`, in the created hook? how does `console.log(this.$refs)` looks like?

Comment: @Ifaruki Added screenshot of the `console.log` output

Comment: @Daniel_Knights the `key` and `ref` are both using 'i' as shown in the `HTML`

Answer (score 1):

When using `v-for`, `ref` maybe array of refs.

Template: use `ref="tests"` instead of `:ref="i"`

```
   <a v-for="(test, i) in tests" :key="i" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" ref="tests" :class="{ 'active': i === 0 }" @click.prevent="selectTest(test)">
        {{ test.test1 }} ({{ test.test2 | capitalize }})
    </a>
```

Script

```
this.$refs.tests[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess its `undefined` because you try to access the element while the `v-for` loop didnt finished its rendering

Try this:

```
methods: {
    findTest() {
        axios.get(END_POINT).then((response) => {
            ...SOMEOTHER CODE
            this.$nextTick(()=> {
               //put your code here
               //this.$refs.0.$el.focus()
               //this.$refs.0.focus();
               //this.$refs.a.$el.children[0].focus();
            })

        }
    }
}
```

Put your code into `$nextTick()` that should ensure that its get executed when the loop is done

Comment: Doesn't work as it errors saying > Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined

Comment: with `//this.$refs[0].focus()` ?